# Not able to query after Alter table in DB2

Tags: db2, dbvisualizer

We have a table someone created in DB2. I have no idea how they created it. But when I edit the table, It edits just fine. But after edit I can not query the table at all [THE COLUMN CANNOT BE ADDED TO THE TABLE BECAUSE THE TABLE HAS AN EDIT PROCEDURE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.codes/n668.htm).

I looked ibm site and found this [how to edit table using procedure](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.admin/db2z_altertables.htm)
But I have no idea how to do this.

Is there anything that I can do to fix this with out following the procedure mentioned in second link?

I restarted server, but still no help. First I'm not able to figure out why I get the error in first place.

I'm using DB Visualizer and DB2 on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sometimes default behavior of DB2. We need to run reorgchk command to fix these errors. More info below..

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000888.htm 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/c0023297.htm